# apply function between two rows with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find the velocity with data of my df :

```
df :
frame  position   times 
1      (x1,y1)    5
2      (x2,y2)    6
10     (x10,y10)  14 
11     (x11,y11)  15
```

I want to add a column `velocity` following this formula : velocity = d/t for each row only if the difference of frame between two rows is less or equal to a value `N=1` for example. `frame` and `time` are strictly increasing

The expected result would be :

```
df_result :
frame  position   time velocity
1      (x1,y1)    5    0
2      (x2,y2)    6    norm((x1,y1),(x2,y2))/(2-1)
10     (x10,y10)  14   NAN
11     (x11,y11)  15   norm((x10,y10),(x11,y11))/(15-14)
```

Is there a way to do that without iterating over the lines ?

EDIT : I have and idea using `shift` method of pandas
`df['velocity] = distance.euclidean(df[position],df[position].shift())/df[frame]-df[frame].shift())`

Comment: I need that these are just representative columns. What is the actual reproducable input? Also, have you attempted it?

Comment: What if there is `3 (x3,y3) 9` below the `2      (x2,y2)    6`?

Comment: frame column is strictly increasing.

Comment: `3 (x3,y3) 9` for this result would be `norm((x2,y2),(x3,y3))/(3-2)` ?? basically you want to clusters row (pairs) together and then apply normalization

Comment: I made a mistake, the velocity is obtained by the difference of `times` and not by `frame` with the condition that the difference of frames of two consecutive rows is less or equal to a value N

Comment: Sorry if this question is stupid but, what is `norm`?

Comment: `norm` is the euclidean distance between two points

Comment: so in you dataframe `(xn,yn)` are numbers?

Comment: Yes, in my case, these positions are on a picture so it's in pixels

Comment: @Pi-R: check my answer. You can modify it as per your need.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Now it's working as you wanted it to be and tested it on some other data also. Working fine now. Can you check and tell me if this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

df:

```
 frame  position time 
0   1   (1,2)       5   
1   2   (3,4)       6   
2   3   (7,9)       6   
3   10  (5,6)       14  
4   11  (7,8)       15
```

try (works only when you are taking consecutive rows):

```
n=1
idx = np.where(df.time.diff()<=n)[0]

val = lambda z: z.position.str[1:-1].str.split(",", expand=True).astype(int)
g = lambda x,y : np.sqrt(np.sum((val(x).values-val(y).values)**2, axis=1))/(x.time.values-y.time.values)

df['velocity'] = 0
df.loc[idx, 'velocity'] = g(df.loc[idx], df.loc[idx-1])
```

---

**df:**

```
    frame   position    time    velocity
0   1       (1,2)       5       0.000000
1   2       (3,4)       6       2.828427
2   3       (7,9)       6       inf
3   10      (5,6)       14      0.000000
4   11      (7,8)       15      2.828427
```

---

**Explanation:**

`val`: is a function which split the column having tuples into a dataframe like this:

```
0 (1,2)
1 (3,4)
```

into (dataframe)

```
0 1
---
1 2
3 4
```

---

`g` : is a function  which does the `norm((x1,y1),(x2,y2))/(2-1)` thing